# Python custom generator of object not efficient

Tags: python, performance, generator

Let's consider the following class `Signal` which defines a multiphasic signal:

```
class Signal:
    def __init__(self, fq, phases):
        self.fq = fq
        self.phases = phases
```

I created a function that generates `Signal` to test in another function.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import itertools

def duo_SBs_to_test(SB1, SB2, frequency_step = 1, shift_step = 50, max_shift = 20000, permutations = True):

    upper_frequency = frequency_step + 1/(2*max(sum(SB1.phases), sum(SB2.phases)))*1000000

    if SB1.fq <= 100 and SB2.fq <= 100:
        r1 = 0.1
        r2 = 0.1
        upper1 = SB1.fq + r1*SB1.fq + frequency_step
        upper2 = SB2.fq + r2*SB2.fq + frequency_step
    elif SB1.fq <= 100 and SB2.fq > 100:
        r1 = 0.1
        r2 = 0.2
        upper1 = SB1.fq + r1*SB1.fq + frequency_step
        upper2 = SB2.fq + r2*SB2.fq + frequency_step
        if upper2 > upper_frequency:
            upper2 = upper_frequency
    elif SB1.fq > 100 and SB2.fq <= 100:
        r1 = 0.2
        r2 = 0.1
        upper1 = SB1.fq + r1*SB1.fq + frequency_step
        upper2 = SB2.fq + r2*SB2.fq + frequency_step
        if upper1 > upper_frequency:
            upper1 = upper_frequency
    else: 
        r1 = 0.2
        r2 = 0.2
        upper1 = SB1.fq + r1*SB1.fq + frequency_step
        upper2 = SB2.fq + r2*SB2.fq + frequency_step
        if upper1 > upper_frequency:
            upper1 = upper_frequency
        if upper2 > upper_frequency:
            upper2 = upper_frequency

    for s, f1, f2 in itertools.product(range(0, max_shift+shift_step, shift_step), 
                                       range(int(SB1.fq - r1*SB1.fq), int(upper1), frequency_step), 
                                       range(int(SB2.fq - r2*SB2.fq), int(upper2), frequency_step)):

        yield (Signal(f1, SB1.phases), Signal(f2, SB2.phases), s)
        if permutations:
            yield (Signal(f2, SB2.phases), Signal(f1, SB1.phases), s)
```

Surprisingly, the performance isn't great. It's my first time creating a generator, and I guess I missed something.

```
%timeit res = [elt for elt in duo_SBs_to_test(SB1, SB3, frequency_step = 1, 
shift_step = 50, max_shift = 20000, permutations = True)]
829 ms ± 11.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit res = [elt for elt in duo_SBs_to_test(SB1, SB3, frequency_step = 1, 
shift_step = 50, max_shift = 20000, permutations = True)]
842 ms ± 13.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit for elt in duo_SBs_to_test(SB1, SB3, frequency_step = 1, 
shift_step = 50, max_shift = 20000, permutations = True): continue
765 ms ± 5.81 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit for elt in duo_SBs_to_test(SB1, SB3, frequency_step = 1, 
shift_step = 50, max_shift = 20000, permutations = True): continue
768 ms ± 5.66 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

The former function I was using was storing `frequency_to_test` in a list, `shifts` in a numpy array before running the `itertools.product()` and storing in a list the `Signals_to_test`. Yet, it was just as fast...

EDIT:

```
SB1 = Signal(50, [300, 50, 900])
SB3 = Signal(80, [300, 50, 900])
```

Thanks for the tips :)

EDIT2: Next step:

```
def compute(SB1, SB2, frequency_step = 1, shift_step = 50, max_shift = 20000, permutations = True):

    result = list()
    for duo_generated in duo_SBs_to_test(SB1, SB2, frequency_step, shift_step, max_shift, permutations):
        if not condition(duo_generated):
            continue
        else:
            result.append(duo_generated)

    return result
```

`condition()` is a function returning a boolean.

Comment: When you `yield (SB(…), SB(…))` do you mean `Signal`? Otherwise, please give the definition of `SB`. Also, could you share the definition of `SB1` and `SB3` so we can recreate your timings.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger Yes, what I need to yield is a list or tuple of object Signals. See Edit for SB1 and SB3. I've taken out the amplitude of the object which is not relevant to this problem. The timing might still differ slightly as my object `Signal`is a bit different

Comment: That doesn't make much sense. If you want to yield `Signal` objects why do you yield these cryptic `SB` objects. Besides, the signature of the constructor does not match (`SB` take 3 parameters, but `Signal` only 2).

Comment: @MathiasEttinger My bad it's fixed! I've just noticed the typo error... SBi are object `Signal`.

Comment: Just removing stuff to make it match what you’re saying isn't going to help. Removing that `s` parameter from the constructor means you could as well remove it from the `product` and get way better performances… Can't you paste your real code instead?

Comment: A generator is not expected to give any speedup in CPU-bound cases like this. Generators can give speedups in I/O-bound cases, if the processing of one item can be done in parallel with waiting for the next one.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger Yes I apologize for the broken example. I wanted to focus on the main part of the generator and took out most of the unnecessary stuff linked to the object. `s` is part of what needs to be yielded, it can be considered as above now.

Comment: @GarethRees Ok I did not know that. I thought that the main advantage is that I didn't have to write every items in memory (ex. in a list) and that I could simply pass them one by one. See EDIT2 for the applicaiton of that generator. It could indeed work in multiprocessing / multithreading since each iteration is independent and since I do not care of the order returned in result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `if`s structure is needlessly complicated. They only set `r1` and `r2` based on simple rules (`r1` [resp. `r2`] is 0.1 if `SB1.fq` [resp. `SB2.fq`] is lower than 100 and 0.2 otherwise) and compute `upper1` and `upper2` using the same formula. So you can use the simpler:

```
r1 = 0.1 if SB1.fq <= 100 else 0.2
r2 = 0.1 if SB2.fq <= 100 else 0.2
upper1 = (1 + r1) * SB1.fq + frequency_step
upper2 = (1 + r2) * SB2.fq + frequency_step
```

You can also use [`min`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) to make these values not go over `upper_frequency`. But this is still some redundancies, especially given the fact that, later, you use `r1` & `SB1` and `r2` & `SB2` in the same kind of pattern in your `range`s. So better extract out a function:

```
def frequency_range(SB, step, higher_frequency):
    r = 0.1 if SB.fq <= 100 else 0.2
    high = (1 + r) * SB.fq + step
    low = (1 - r) * SB.fq
    return range(int(low), int(min(high, higher_frequency)))
```

And the main function is now:

```
def duo_SBs_to_test(SB1, SB2, frequency_step=1, shift_step=50, max_shift=20000, permutations=True):
    max_phases = max(sum(SB1.phases), sum(SB2.phases))
    upper_frequency = frequency_step + 1/(2 * max_phases) * 1000000

    parameters = itertools.product(
            range(0, max_shift + shift_step, shift_step),
            frequency_range(SB1, frequency_step, upper_frequency),
            frequency_range(SB2, frequency_step, upper_frequency))

    for s, f1, f2 in parameters:
        yield Signal(f1, SB1.phase), Signal(f2, SB2.phase), s
        if permutations:
            yield Signal(f2, SB2.phase), Signal(f1, SB1.phase), s
```

Now the only little change that I can think of that could improve performances is to avoid testing `permutations` at each iteration. So you could perform two "radicaly" different iterations depending on the value of `permutations`:

```
def duo_SBs_to_test(SB1, SB2, frequency_step=1, shift_step=50, max_shift=20000, permutations=True):
    max_phases = max(sum(SB1.phases), sum(SB2.phases))
    upper_frequency = frequency_step + 1/(2 * max_phases) * 1000000

    parameters = itertools.product(
            range(0, max_shift + shift_step, shift_step),
            frequency_range(SB1, frequency_step, upper_frequency),
            frequency_range(SB2, frequency_step, upper_frequency))

    if permutations:
        for s, f1, f2 in parameters:
            yield Signal(f1, SB1.phase), Signal(f2, SB2.phase), s
            yield Signal(f2, SB2.phase), Signal(f1, SB1.phase), s
    else:
        for s, f1, f2 in parameters:
            yield Signal(f1, SB1.phase), Signal(f2, SB2.phase), s
```

---

Now, as regard to your next step, you’re basically just reinventing [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter). Just use that instead:

```
def compute(SB1, SB2, frequency_step = 1, shift_step = 50, max_shift = 20000, permutations = True):
    return list(filter(condition, duo_SBs_to_test(SB1, SB2, frequency_step, shift_step, max_shift, permutations))
```

And if that `compute` function is called in a `for` loop, you can also remove the need to convert it to a list.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for the bumpy start with the typos mistakes. I will test this tomorrow. Thanks for pointing out the `filter()` function. I was not aware of it. I'm using several conditions to validate an input, thus I might need to filter several time. I will test the efficiency tomorrow.